# Change form action and verb on button click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form that has a main submit button that needs to use POST and a specific action, but I also have a couple of buttons that need to submit the form using GET and to different actions.

The only way I could see to do this was to intercept the submit using a jQuery .click() event and passing the form vars using something like this:

```
$('#btnClick').click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault;

    input = $(':input');
    window.location.href = '/action/?' + input;

    return false;    
})
```

This makes a messy querystring and exposes some hidden fields that contain lengthy data. What is the best way of using jQuery to intercept form submission and resending using GET?

Btw, I am targeting different MVC GET Controller Actions with a couple of buttons while the main button uses POST to the Controller Action of the current view.

**EDIT**

Though I haven't tried it yet, Mike provided an idea I hadn't thought of. I could do something like:

```
$("form").attr("action", "/action");
$("form").attr("method", "post");
```

or

```
$("form").attr("action", "/action");
$("form").attr("method", "get");
```

but the latter will still expose some vars that are messy, mainly hidden fields. Is there a way of excluding the hidden fields without manually manipulating the querystring?

Comment: I'm going to say handle the submit event and use ajax. Without ajax you could probably change it. Never tried it though.

Comment: I guess I've never used Ajax while redirecting to another page. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: No I was saying if you using ajax you can intercept what they are doing in the submit event. If not you can probably just change the form method attribute on the form itself. That's what I would try first. I do so much ajax these days...

Comment: The form has a button that submits using POST and a couple of others that submit using GET.

Comment: To intercept form submission you handle the submit event in jquery. To cancel entirely just return false. You MIGHT be able to do something like $("form").attr("method", "post").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd probably be best to disable the fields you don't want so they aren't submitting, and the form can work like normal otherwise. So if for example, by default you have the form submitting via POST, but you have another button `#search` which does a GET but you want to exclude some elements:

```
$('#search').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault;
    $(this)
        .parents("form")
            .find("input.excludeOnSearch")
                .prop("disabled", true)
            .end()
            .attr("method", "GET")
            .submit();
})
```

Comment: I like this. Nice solution to prevent unwanted fields from being submitted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://jsbin.com/cakov/1/edit?html,js,output

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  var method = $("form").attr("method");
  if(method === "POST") {
    $("form").attr("method", "GET");
  } else {
    $("form").attr("method", "POST");
  }

  alert($("form").attr("method"));

  return false;
});
```

This code effectively acts a toggle and changes the http method to, in this case, the opposite of what it was. The final return statement cancels the submit of the form.

I think this is what you are asking?

Comment: Mike, you definitely provided me with a better option and dyagmin expanded on it. I think his answer will work the way I'm needing. Wish I could mark both of your answers as correct. ;)